# Calling a Jquery function from variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to call Jquery functions using a variable value.

Let consider below scenario:

```
               var func = "append";   
               $(document).func("<div>Append Welcome</div>");
               func = "prepend";   
               $(document).func("<div> Prepend Welcome</div>");
               func = "html";   
               $(document).func("<div> Insert Html Welcome</div>");
```

I can use if and else but is there any way to achieve as above.

Is this a good way to do or simply use if and else?

Comment: Try `$(document)[func]("<div>Append Welcome</div>");`

Answer (score 3):

Functions can be accessed using `[]` syntax, just like regular properties of an object:

```
var func = "append";   
$(document)[func]("<div>Append Welcome</div>");
func = "prepend";   
$(document)[func]("<div> Prepend Welcome</div>");
func = "html";   
$(document)[func]("<div> Insert Html Welcome</div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call a function using a variable name with bracket notation:
https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/mw4hm5ma/

```
var app = {
    alert : function(message){
    alert(message)
    }
}
var funcName = "alert"

app[funcName]('this is a message')
```

I'm creating an object with a method inside... then I can use the variable value as a name for that function ex `Object[variable](arguments)`

I hope this helps...