# Calling a function by it's name from a variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to call a function from a variable containing it's name.

More precisely, my idea is to have a timed "master" function, which will call a set of functions every n seconds.

The set of functions to call would be defined in an array, populated by names based on the called page.

Found this in jquery: [Calling a Jquery function from variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250974/calling-a-jquery-function-from-variable-value)  but no luck.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thnx.

**EDTI**

Here's a stub of code i'm working on:

```
var exec = "updateClock";
var updateClock = function () {
     //something nice here :)
};

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $scope.$apply([exec]);
}, 15000);
```

Comment: You should share the code of what you have tried. You can store function references in variables or with angular in $scope variables. Maybe if you show what you have tried it would be easier to help. Functions calling other functions is called functional programming and is very common in javascript :).

Comment: why strings? You can store references to functions themselves.

Comment: Pages are generated dynamically, each page has it's own set. So the idea is to write the function array server side.

Comment: Make the function a property on an object and then `someObject[exec].call()`.

Comment: Ok, I like the object approach. Will give it a try.